# Use of "string.strip()"

Tags: python, string, strip

I am trying to remove all punctuation signs from a string using ".strip()", but its not working

```
sentence = "The sunset sets at twelve o' clock." 
new_sentence = sentence.strip("!@#$%^&*()'-_+={}[]|\:;'<>?,./\"")**

print(new_sentence)
#result : The sunset sets at twelve o' clock    
#Expectation : The sunset sets at twelve o clock
```

Answer (score 1):

Strip only removes from the beginning and the end of the string. Since you are looking to change punctuation inside the overall string, strip will not work.

You can always use strip for punctuation at the ends of the string and then search through the string for other instances of punctuation by using list comprehension. Or perhaps build a new string going from the first index to the last containing only values that are not punctuation marks:

```
result = ""
punctuation = ["!@#$%^&*()'-_+={}[]|\:;'<>?,./\"")**]
for character in sentence:
    same = False
    for punc in punctuation:
        if punc == character:
            same = True
    if not same:
        result += i
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.strip` won't work for the reasons Sondering Narcissist gave, but you can use `string.punctuation` with a generator expression:

```
import string

def stripped(s, chars):
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c not in chars)

sentence = "The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."
stripped(sentence, string.punctuation)
# 'The sunset sets at twelve o clock'
```